# Django wont load media files from filefield to template

Tags: django

I want to display and audio stored in filefield but the links comes up dead even though when i upload files to through admin they are showing up in the media directory but are giving dead links in when page loads i even tried to change it from audio to an image with appropriate data still nothing

```
#template
{% for audios in Audios %}
<audio controls>
    <source src="{{ audios.Audio_File.url }}" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
{% endfor %}

#settings.py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

#urls.py
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
dja
```

Also here is the entire settings file just incase

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'kv=%#$g8bjbu+b6)#(z@5kp2*-40rz6e6&3h$6dpt$&55+jep@'


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'speak.apps.SpeakConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'speakEnglish.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'speakEnglish.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}   


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Do you see 404 errors in your browser's developer panel?

Comment: Nope it goes through fine and the url {{audios.Audio_File.url}} gives is media/CorrectFileName.mp3

Comment: What is the content type? (check your network panel in the browser development tools)

Comment: only the static files for the css i have used are showing up nothing else

Comment: What happens when you browse to `http://localhost:8000/media/CorrectFileName.mp3` ?

Comment: It take me to http://localhost:8000 page but the url bar has this url:http://localhost:8000/media/CorrectFileName.mp3

Comment: So you probably have a bug in your urls.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i missed the $ in one of my urls.py

what i had

```
url(r'^', views.index, name='index'),
```

what i changed to

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

It took me more than 24 hours to figure it out but i still dont know why only the files that i wanted to get were affected